# which delegate method is called when cross button of keyboard is click in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am facing problem in finding which delegate method is called when the cross button of the keyboard is pressed, when the text field is empty in iOS. When the text field is not empty, it calls the method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
}
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Cross button? What's that?

Comment: do you mean backspace?

Comment: yes i mean backspace -user2476934

Comment: Are you trying to remove all text when cross (backspace) button is pressed??

Comment: When the user presses the backspace button the replacementString will be an empty string @"" and the range.length will be greater than zero.

Comment: actually the textfields are password fields and i have four text fields and one textfields can have only one character and i want to clear the text field by pressing the backspace button

Comment: Good question, never think for this before, can you share the purpose of checking this?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Comment: This delegate will be call only when a user taps on a cross button on `UITextField`.